# Is memtest86 self-contained or does it have an underlying OS?

Tags: intel

I'm trying to convince Intel that I have a hardware problem, but they say it is a problem with the Linux OS, and that I should use Windows instead.

The hardware has the same problem when I boot from a memtest86 USB, but I don't know for sure that memtest86 doesn't also rely on a Linux kernel.

Please confirm or deny that memtest86 uses Linux.

Comment: If that's a simple open source program, why can't just send source code to Intel tell them this code can reproduce the problem and slap on their face?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克,  **最好和羔羊说话而不是与老虎搏斗。**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memtest86 is self-contained, it doesn’t rely on an underlying OS. (I’m using memtest86+ here but the answer is the same for memtest86+ and memtest86.) Its boot process is described in [the `README.background` file](https://sources.debian.org/src/memtest86+/5.01-3.1/README.background/); it goes from boot to running memory tests without any operating system being involved.

There are however parts of the source code which are copied from the Linux kernel; for example, [`head.S`](https://sources.debian.org/src/memtest86+/5.01-3.1/head.S/) originally came from Linux. This copied code is a very small part of memtest86+, and memtest86+ is much simpler than Linux, so I wouldn’t let that be used as the basis for any argument over the validity of the memory tests’ results.

Comment: They finally said they'd honour the warranty.  The link to how memtest86 loads probably helped a lot.  Thanks.  Why they assume everyone runs Windows and they don't have their own stand-alone diagnostic program, I've no idea.  It's not like Intel is a small company.